# Formatting an input cell

Tags: formatting

I want to create an input cell with two lines, like the following:

```
a="aaaaaaa";
b="bbbbbb"; c="ccccc";
```

That is as I want to have it. Now insert in the first string some more characters `a`. When the length of the string is about 60 (slightly over halfway the notebook line), the assignment to `c` moves to the next line. The only way I can put it back to the second line is to use a carriage return after the assignment to `c`, resulting in an empty third line, which I do not want to see either.

My feeling is that this annoying behaviour is due to some notebook settings, but I have no idea which ones. How do I keep the assignments to `b` and `c` on one line, without creating an empty third line?

Comment: You can type `\[NoBreak]` before `c` but I guess you want something more robust and user friendly. Maybe there is an option that governs this but I don't remember any. I use Code cells if I want to control indentation etc.

Comment: It might actually be a bug. I ran into this many times and always found it very annoying.

Comment: @Kuba. That works, thanks! I did not know that such a symbol exists. But it only corrects something that should not happen.

Answer (score 2):

Start with input cell containing

```
a="aaaaaaa";
b="bbbbbb"; c="ccccc";
```

From the Format menu select Word Wrapping / Don't word wrap. Then insert more 'a', it does not wrap.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this problem. Your solution works nicely, but only when the length of the first line is less than the window width. If it is longer (say a compound expression with many short arguments), then I think it is not a good idea to switch off automatic line breaking.